# I'm setting a nested list and I don't know what style should I use

Tags: html, css

I want a solution for nested list styles, see the code:

```html
<ul>
  <li>nesteds
    <ul>
      <li>nested 1</li>
      <li>nested 2</li>
      <li>nested 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to align nested **1 and 2 and 3** exactly in the bottom of **nesteds**. What should I do?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried, especially how have you styled the outer "nesteds" element, because without any styles the list **is** as the bottom, because it's the only thing in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `padding:0;` to `ul` because you need to override browsers default `css` by setting `padding:0;` to `ul`

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <ul>

    <li>nesteds

      <ul>
        <li>nested 1</li>
        <li>nested 2</li>
        <li>nested 3</li>
      </ul>

    </li>

  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will remove the `ul` indentation.

```css
.non-indentation {
  padding: 0;
  /* Add this declaration if you want to remove list bullets. */
  /* list-style-type: none; */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>nesteds
    <ul class="non-indentation">
      <li>nested 1</li>
      <li>nested 2</li>
      <li>nested 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try add

> [display:inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```css
.list{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>
      nesteds
      <ul class="list">
        <li>nested 1</li>
        <li>nested 2</li>
        <li>nested 3</li> 
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
```